# Distribution over functions that integrate to 0

Tags: distributions, gaussian-process, measure-theory

This question is about Gaussian processes interpreted as distributions over the space of functions.  Gaussian processes have the property that their integrals are Gaussian random variables; cf. [this StackExchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570858/integral-of-a-gaussian-process-has-gaussian-distribution/1129990) for a derivation.  In particular, the integral of a zero-mean Gaussian process $X(t)$ over $t$ is almost always *non*zero.

**Does there exist a "canonical" distribution over functions $X(t)$ over $[0,1]^n$ that integrate to zero (almost always)?**

Ideally, it'd be great to identify a distribution that's easy to work with computationally, e.g. one for which we can draw samples of $X(t_k)$ for some fixed/finite set of values $t_k\in[0,1]^n$.

Of course the simplest thing to do would be to subtract the mean, i.e. to take a standard zero-mean Gaussian process $X(t)$ and define a new function $X_{\mathrm{centered}}(t):=X(t)-\mathbb E_{t\in[0,1]}[X(t)]$, but I'm worried that this distribution is hard to work with computationally because it couples different $t$ values together in a way that requires knowing $X(t)$ for all $t$ to evaluate the function.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge#General_case ?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I see it.  Seems like the Brownian bridge gives a function that "connects" two values but doesn't have a guarantee on the integral over t.  I need that P(a function has nonzero integral)=0, not that the expected integral is zero.  Does that make sense?  Thanks!

Comment: The Brownian Bridge is itself the integral of its increments, is it not?

Comment: Afraid I don't know this area well enough to interpret what this means.  Is the idea to make a Brownian bridge and then somehow differentiate it in $t$?

Comment: Brownian motion / a Weiner process is an example of a Gaussian process; its value at time $t$ is Gaussian and is the "integral" of its increments $dW_s$.  A generalized Brownian bridge appears to have all the properties you requested in your question.

Comment: I'm afraid I just don't see this.  It seems like the *expected* integral of the Brownian bridge might be zero, but that the probability of a nonzero-integral is potentially nonzero.  If you have a clearer reference I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: The (generalized) bridge is itself the integral you speak of. Its endpoint (the value of the integral) is fixed. You don't *integrate* the bridge, it's already integrated, and that integral has all the stated properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding the distribution and sampling from it should be straightforward for continuous covariance and mean functions which have readily computable integrals.

Let us assume for convenience that $X$ is defined on $[0;1]$, zero-mean with continuous covariance function $K$. It should not be very difficult to generalise from this. Define $Y=\int_0^1X(s)ds$ as your integrated process.

#### Existence and properties of $Y$

If $$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 K(s,t)dsdt < \infty$$
then $Y$ is a constant Gaussian process, i.e. a Gaussian random variable. This random variable (not the process) is zero mean and has covariance $C=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 K(s,t)dsdt$.

#### Joint properties of $(X,Y)$

$X$ and $Y$ are joint Gaussian processes, i.e. they have a joint Gaussian distribution. Their cross covariance function is 
$$ Cov(X(t),Y) = \int_0^1 K(s,t)ds.$$

#### Conditioning on Y

As it is true for any Gaussian process, conditioning $(X,Y)$ on $Y$ will give you a Gaussian process again. So define the new Gaussian process as 
$$Z = X | Y=0$$

#### Sampling from $Z$

Using the conditioning formula for Gaussian processes you can draw samples from $Z$ in pretty much the same way as you would draw samples from $X$.

A paper describing this in more depth and generality is "Linear Operators and Stochastic Partial Differential Equations in Gaussian Process Regression" by Simo Särkkä. Available online [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221079156_Linear_Operators_and_Stochastic_Partial_Differential_Equations_in_Gaussian_Process_Regression).

Comment: This is a nice idea!  Seems to be a reasonable thing to do for our problem --- thanks so much.